# Custom Average Calcualtion based on date in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I have one table like

| ID | Date. | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 2022-04-25 | 3.546 |
| 2. | 2022-03-13 | 5.67 |
| 1 | 2022-04-12 | 3.459 |
| 1 | 2022-05-20 | 3.678 |

I want average of in such a way that for each month and ID I have average of Rate . So for Jan it will be from first working day i.e 3rd Jan to 5 working days before the 1st of next month.. So similarly for June the average would be from 3rd Jan to 25th June and similarly for each month..

The query I'm using currently is

```
Select Id, Avg(Rate), Month(Date), Year(Date) 
from table 
group by month(date), Year(Date), ID.
```

Which is not correct so currently I'm thinking of defining a variable as Firstday for the first monday of the year and so the lst day.. but how would I be able to calculate avg based on time difference is I'm not sure.

Could anyone please help me achieve this.

Comment: And your current query and error(s) are? Can you share this please else we can't help

Comment: Sounds like you need to join a calendar table

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Tag the engine you are actually using.

Comment: Definitely sounds like you need a [Calendar Table](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+calendar+table), because different countries have different working days - or even different years have different working days and trying to build this logic into a query is needlessly complicated. It is much easier to set all the bank holidays once, and then reference that static table over and over again